# How to set android TabLayout programmatically in the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

My question is how I can set the new android material design TabLayout to be in the bottom of the screen, kind of like Instagram's bottom toolbar.

Comment: Can you show the layout and code you already have please

Answer (score 0):

It's not `TabLayout`, It's `BottomNavigationView` and you can read more about it [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/) or check this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/).